# How to clean up a bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, bitmap

I'm creating a new empty transparent `Bitmap` and making some modifications to it.

Is there a way to clean up this (make transparent and empty again) without creating new instance of `Bitmap`?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your help.
I have found answer.

```
// Fills the bitmap's pixels with the specified Color. 
bitmap.eraseColor(somecolor);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
myBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The constant int value of TRANSPARENT is 0x00000000.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bitmap must be a mutable Bitmap.

when your bitmap like this

Bitmap bitmap=.......

then convert it into mutable bitmap by using below

Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

then 
mutableBitmap.eraseColor(somecolor);